# Adding Custom Font to Xamarin without crashing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've added a font file to my Android project called Cedarville-Cursive. Its build action is as an Android asset and when I want to use it in my MainPage, I call it like this:

```
<Label.FontFamily>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <On Platform="Android">Cedarville-Cursive.ttf#Cedarville</On>
    </OnPlatform>
</Label.FontFamily>
```

Within a

```
<Label> </Label>
```

obviously but when I do this, the Android app doesn't start with the Xamarin Live Player. The console says it's deployed but the screen doesn't switch to the app. When I comment out the:

```
<On Platform="Android">Cedarville-Cursive.ttf#Cedarville</On>
```

part, it functions normally so what's going wrong has to be here. Any ideas?

EDIT
I've seen that the error I receive on the phone says: "Target of add is null..."

Comment: Try changing it to `<On Platform="Android" Value="Cedarville-Cursive.ttf#Cedarville" />`, or `<On Platform="Android"><On.Value>Cedarville-Cursive.ttf#Cedarville</On.Value></On>`

Comment: Neither of those work sadly. They still bring up the same issue where the app doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I realize this is a bit older and you may have gotten it fixed by now but I had this same exact issue/error. I fixed it by going into the Settings on my device under-

Device Management-->Storage-->Apps-->Xamarin Live Player-->Storage

and clearing all of its stored data and cache. This was on a Samsung SM-G955U.

I had to do this even after I uninstalled and reinstalled Live Player.

I found your question while I was looking for the answer so figured I'd chime in in case anyone else is in the same situation.